# Java Swing Component Problems in Linux

Tags: java, linux, swing

I've a Java Swing application which is working as intended in Windows. However in Linux (RedHat7) I'm having the following issues;

2. Whenever a `JButton` is clicked which is responsible for changing components (like buttons or labels) in a `JPanel`, new components are not fully painted until I mouse-over them.

These are all working fine in Windows but not in Linux. Can anyone help me to understand what might be going wrong here?

Comment: *"Can anyone help me to understand what might be going wrong here?"* The 2nd one, the code. post a [mcve]. The first one, no idea. I'll wait until you decide which of the two problems you'd like to ask a question about, and edit the other into a new question thread (also with relevant MCVE & a question) before I advise further.

Comment: You re-asked question 1 in another posting, so you should remove it from hear so that all suggestion in in one place and everybody know what has been suggested.

Answer (score 1):

> 2.Whenever a JButton is clicked which is responsible for changing components (like buttons or labels) in a JPanel, new components are not fully painted until I mouse-over them.

Make sure you are using layout managers.

When you add components to a visible GUI the basic code is:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```